# Grunt Upload to AWS S3 with Virtual Hosting URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gruntjs

I'm trying to use Grunt to upload assets to an Amazon S3 Bucket, however I'm running into some issues.

I'm using `grunt-aws-s3` https://github.com/MathieuLoutre/grunt-aws-s3

I'm trying to upload to `https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com` instead of the default `https://s3.amazonaws.com` url.

Everytime I run the task, it says that it's trying to upload to https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucketname